# Convergence in probability

Tags: probability

I need to prove that given the r.v. Xn  with the same distribution functions, the sequence of r.v. Xn/n tends to 0 in probability.
Following the definition i find:

P(|Xn/n| > a) = P(|Xn| > na) for a>0. I don't understand why the probability of the Events will tend to 0 when n tends to infinity. Imagine the sequence Xn is divergent. Is it the strict inequality which makes sensless the expression infinity > infinity that divergence cant occur and thus the probability is zero ?

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let it be that all $X_n$ have the same distribution as some random variable $X$ (you could choose for $X:=X_1$).

Then $P(|X_n|>na)=P(|X|>na)$ for each $n$.

Do you understand that $P(|X|>na)$ tends to $0$ if $n$ tends to $\infty$ and $a>0$?